# Vuetify date-picker does not show last week of month

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Using Vuetify `v-date-picker` I discovered that it does not show the last week of the month on Android devices, the same happens on computer with Google Chrome when zooming in. I could not reproduce it, because another `v-date-picker` on Vuetify's website rendered correctly and I could not spot the difference in code.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to the change of padding on small screens. It can be solved by applying the following CSS:

```css
<style>
  /* Setting padding to 0 prevents hiding last week of the month on mobile devices */
  div.v-date-picker-table > table > tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
</style>
``
```